# How does migration work with the new closing system?

Tags: support, migration

The old migration dialog appears to have gone the way of the dodo as part of [the recent overhaul of the closing system](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/06/the-war-of-the-closes/).

How does it work now? Does migration still exist? If five people vote to close a question on Stack Overflow as "general computing hardware and software", does it go to Super User?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Migration still exists. Just click on *"This belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network"*. You'll find the migration targets there.

> [image: Glorious migration targets will appear]